# using angular.injector with ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-injector

I have included "ngAnimate" as a dependency to my ngApp.

Now in a jQuery file, I am trying to access this using :

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'angular-sm']).invoke(['$compile', '$timeout' ,function ($compile, $timeout) {
```

But this gives me an error of

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $animate <- $compile
```

And then I changed this to :

```
angular.injector(['ng','ngAnimate', 'angular-sm']).invoke(['$compile', '$timeout' ,function ($compile, $timeout) {

angular.injector(['ng','ngAnimate', 'angular-sm']).invoke(['$animate','$compile', '$timeout' ,function ($animate,$compile, $timeout) {
```

And these DIDN'T work either.

Then I tried:

```
var app_element = document.querySelector('[ng-app=angular-sm]');
            angular.element(app_element).injector().invoke(['$compile', '$timeout' ,function($compile,$timeout) {
```

i.e I took the injector of the ngApp defined and it worked. Why so ?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one `$injector` in an Angular application, and you can get it using

```
angular.injector('rootModule')
```

or

```
angular.element(document).injector()
```

In your case it wasn't the root module so you had an error.